# How to fix "Illegal datatype context" (use -XDatatypeContexts)?

Tags: haskell

I am a new learner of Haskell, my code is as follows:

```
data Num a=>Units a = Units a (SymbolicManip a )

      deriving (Eq)
```

I am not sure how to fix it?

Anyone can help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell line of code not compiling: "Illegal datatype context"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934882/haskell-line-of-code-not-compiling-illegal-datatype-context)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Typeclass contexts in datatypes are now regarded as a not so useful feature. The problem is that the following does not compile:

```
foo :: Units a -> a
foo (Units x _) = x+x
```

This intuitively should compile, since the `Units a` argument can only be constructed for a type `a` satisfying `Num a`. So, on destruction (pattern matching) one should be able to access the `Num a` instance. However this is not the case, and a `Num a` must be counterintuitively *provided* on destruction as well:

```
foo :: Num a => Units a -> a
foo (Units x _) = x+x
```

The standard suggestion is therefore to remove the constraint `Num a` from the `Units a` datatype declaration, and add it instead to every function involving `Units a`.

Another option is to enable GADTs and change the datatype to:

```
data Units a where
   Units :: Num a => a -> SymbolicManip a -> Units a
```

This does the "right" thing: a `Num a` instance is required to *construct* a value, and is instead provided on *destruction*. In this way, the first `foo` declaration above will be well-typed.

---

I almost forgot the "quick & dirty" option, which is to enable the obsolescent datatype context feature: this is done by adding at the beginning of your file the line

```
{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}
```

Still, I would rather modify the code than to enable this language extension.

Comment: Instead of invoking all of `GADTs`, I think `ExistentialQuantification` would do.