# MaybeT's m in Type Signature

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Looking at `MaybeT`:

```
λ: import Monad.Trans
λ: import Monad.Trans.Maybe
λ: :t MaybeT
MaybeT :: m (Maybe a) -> MaybeT m a
```

In `MaybeT`'s signature, can `m` be any higher-kinded type, i.e. `* -> *`?

I'm trying to learn Monad Transformers, so I was curious why the `m` did not have a constraint of `Monad`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#type-parameters):

> Another example of a parameterized type that we've already met is **`Map k v`** from **`Data.Map`**. The **`k`** is the type of the keys in a map and the **`v`** is the type of the values. This is a good example of where type parameters are very useful. Having maps parameterized enables us to have mappings from any type to any other type, as long as the type of the key is part of the **`Ord`** type class. If we were defining a mapping type, we could add a type class constraint in the *data* declaration:
>
> ```
> data (Ord k) => Map k v = ...
> ```
>
> However, it is a very strong convention in Haskell to **never add type class constraints in data declarations**. Why? Well, because we don't benefit a lot, but we end up writing more class constraints, even when we don't need them. If we put or don't put the **`Ord k`** constraint in the *data* declaration for **`Map k v`**, we're going to have to put the constraint into functions that assume the keys in a map can be ordered. But if we don't put the constraint in the data declaration, we don't have to put **`(Ord k) =>`** in the type declarations of functions that don't care whether the keys can be ordered or not. An example of such a function is **`toList`**, that just takes a mapping and converts it to an associative list. It's type signature is **`toList :: Map k a -> [(k, a)]`**. If **`Map k v`** had a type constraint in its *data* declaration, the type for **`toList`** would have to be **`toList :: Ord k => Map k a -> [(k, a)]`**, even though the function doesn't do any comparing of keys by order.
>
> So don't put type constraints into *data* declarations even if it seems to make sense, because you'll have to put them into the function type declarations either way.

I hope that answers your question. Although the `m` in `MaybeT m a` is unconstrained yet there is an implicit assumption that `m` is an instance of `Monad`. In fact, if `m` is not an instance of `Monad` then you wouldn't be able to do much with a `MaybeT m a` value because most functions would require that `m` be an instance of `Monad`.

Answer (score 3):

> In `MaybeT`'s signature, can `m` be any higher-kinded type, i.e. `* -> *`?

No:

```
> :k MaybeT
MaybeT :: (* -> *) -> * -> *
```

So, the `m` in the type `MaybeT m a` *must* be exactly of kind `* -> *`, and not of any other kind.

For instance, note the kind error below:

```
> :k MaybeT (State Int)
MaybeT (State Int) :: * -> *

> :k MaybeT State
    Expecting one more argument to ‘State’
    The first argument of ‘MaybeT’ should have kind ‘* -> *’,
      but ‘State’ has kind ‘* -> * -> *’
    In a type in a GHCi command: MaybeT (State)
```

Answer (score 2):

> can `m` be any higher-kinded type, i.e. `* -> *`?

It can be anything with kind `* -> *`. Other than that, there are no restrictions in principle.

> why the `m` did not have a constraint of `Monad`.

The constraint is provided through the types of the functions that use `MaybeT`, rather than through the `MaybeT` constructor. Adding constraints to constructors is not useful unless GADTs are involved (I believe *transformers* does not use GADTs for the sake of simplicity and compliance to the standard). See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18934882/2751851) for extra commentary on constraints and datatype declarations.